# Matrix interpretation of system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

In the [Deep Learning Book](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/), I encountered this:

> To analyze how many solutions the equation has, we can think of the columns of $A$ as specifying different directions we can travel from the origin (the point specified by the vector of all zeros), and determine how many ways there are of reaching $b$. In this view, each element of x specifies how far we should travel in each of these directions.

1) shouldn't it be **rows** of $A$ instead of **columns** of $A$? Wouldn't the columns of $A$ be just numbers from different equations realted to *one Dimension* like $X$, $Y$,...

2) with above definition,is this formula correct?:

Ax = $\sum_{i} x_iA_{:,i}$

how is the sum becomes a vector?

Thank you

Comment: No. It's columns. This is what Gilbert Strang calls the "column picture". The "row picture" is the intersection of hyperplanes.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo but if we take the columns, how those are related to the original linear equations?

Comment: You wrote it already. $\rm A x$ is a linear combination of the columns of $\rm A$. We want to find the coefficients $x_1, \dots, x_n$ such that the linear combination equals $\rm b$.

Comment: thanks @RodrigodeAzevedo ! much appreciated.